# Diagnosing slow requests between Varnish and Nginx

Tags: performance

I have been trying to diagnose slow page load time in my local Drupal 7 environment when using Varnish.

My local environment runs in Docker using docker-compose. I have a containerised Varnish instance, and another container with Nginx and PHP-fpm running in it. The Varnish instance listens on port 80 and caches correctly. The slow page load times occur when a page is not available in the cache and Varnish has to request it from Nginx. Nginx runs on port 8080. I'm also able to request the homepage of my site directly from Nginx on port 8080, bypassing Varnish altogether.

I've been timing requests to my homepage with curl:

Direct to Nginx on port 8080:

```
curl -w%{time_starttransfer} -o /dev/null -s "http://localhost:8080"
1.152%
```

Via Varnish, but with a random string to force the request to come from Nginx:

```
curl -w%{time_starttransfer} -o /dev/null -s "http://localhost?9"
13.896%
```

As shown by the figures below the commands, a request to Nginx on port 8080 takes around 1 second, whereas a request to Nginx via Varnish takes almost 14 seconds.

I've examined the Nginx logs and the transfer times shown there are almost the same as the transfer times shown by curl. This suggests to me that the problem lies in Nginx or PHP-Fpm, rather than Varnish itself. Perhaps there's something different about the request Varnish makes to Nginx compared to requesting the page from Nginx directly?

I've tried profiling the performance using XHProf. When making the request via Varnish, XHProf shows the _drupal_shutdown_function() as having an EWall% of 78%, apparently accounting for a large part of the page load time.

[image: xhprof output described]

When making a request directly to Nginx, _drupal_shutdown_function() does not even show up on the XHProf report.

Strangely, I've tried commenting out all the code inside _drupal_shutdown_function(), but when making another request via Varnish, page load time is unchanged.

- Could anyone explain why XHProf reports _drupal_shutdown_function() as being so slow?
- Is it possible that XHProf is showing misleading data and that the _drupal_shutdown_function() issue is a wild goose chase?
- Could there be another difference in the way Varnish requests a page from Nginx compared to a direct request from Nginx that would account for the slow page load time?

Thank you!